# Python(Pandas), append new column for each new file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a matrix from multiple files. Each of these files has a list of gene names, of various lengths.

To create the matrix I need to group all the gene names from all the files in the first column.

Then for each file append a new column(with the file name as header) and if the gene name is in the appended list add value 1 to the cell, else if the gene name in the first column is not found in the new column appended add zero.

This is what I got until now:

```
import os

files= os.listdir("/gene_files")

df01 = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    file_name = "/gene_files/" + file
    for file in file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header = 0)
    df01 = pd.concat(df01,df)
df01.to_csv('gene_matrix.csv')
```

This gives me all the gene lists in one column. I then drop all the duplicates.

```
df01 = df01.drop_duplicates
```

Now I need to append a new column for each file, evaluate if geneName(file) is in first column and add 1s or 0s accordingly. I'm stuck.... and also utterly confused.

The files look like this:

```
File1          File2         File3          etc...

GeneName      GeneName       GeneName
  A              B              A
  B              C              B
  C              D              E
  F              E              F
```

The output I want would be a matrix/dataframe:

```
GeneName  File1    File2   File3
A           1        0       1  
B           1        1       1
C           1        1       0
D           0        1       0 
E           0        1       1 
F           1        0       1
```

These are the actual first few lines of the files:

```
     fileAIB          fileAIC           fileAID
     Plekha4           Dffb             Rabggta
    1700012D01Rik     A430033K04Rik      Sc5d
     Isg20             Tubb3            Gnpnat1
     Smad6             Rbm17            Nabp1
     Ndufa10           Isg20            Isg20
     Wdr90             Arrb2            Lrrc27
     Thumpd1           Ankrd13c         Add3
     Cd2bp2            Ndufa10          Prkaa1
     Cndp2             Inpp5e           Gmeb2
     Jmjd1c            Lamtor2          B4galt7
```

And the output would look like:

```
GeneName    fileAIB       fileAIC           fileAID
Plekha4         1            0                 0
1700012D01Rik   1            0                 0
Isg20           1            1                 1
Smad6           1            0                 0
Ndufa10         1            0                 0
Wdr90           1            0                 0
Thumpd1         1            0                 0
Cd2bp2          1            0                 0
Rbm17           1            0                 1
Jmjd1c          1            0                 0
Dffb            0            1                 0
A430033K04Rik   0            1                 0
Tubb3           0            1                 1
Rbm17           0            1                 0
Arrb2           0            1                 0
Ankrd13c        0            1                 0
Ndufa10         0            1                 0
Gnpnat1         0            1                 0
Lamtor2         0            1                 0
Rabggta         0            0                 1
Sc5d            0            0                 1
Gnpnat1         0            0                 1
Lrrc27          0            0                 1
Prkaa1          0            0                 1
Gmeb2           0            0                 1
B4galt7         0            0                 1
```

Comment: Why the second `for` loop which lines thereafter would not compile due to indentation? And what is `geneName()`? A defined function? Please show some data to illustrate.

Comment: oh sorry.. the () was just to clarify that I need to compare the geneNames from the file to the first column. Didn't even think it would look like a function.

Comment: Can we see contents of file? And dataframe, especially first column? Desired result would be great, too. Just a few rows needed. Help us help you.

Comment: Edited the question to include some of the content. Is this okay? I wasn't sure how to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider appending all text file data into a long form dataframe and then pivoting to wide format:

```
dfList = []

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header = None, names = ['GeneName'])        
    df = df.assign(file = file.replace('.txt', ''), num = 1)
    dfList.append(df)

finaldf = pd.concat(dfList)

# PIVOT (LONG TO WIDE)
finaldf = finaldf.pivot_table(index=['GeneName'], columns=['file'], 
                              values='num', aggfunc='count').fillna(0).reset_index()    
# CONVERT TO INTEGER
numcols = list(range(1,len(finaldf.columns)))
finaldf.ix[:,numcols] = finaldf.ix[:,numcols].astype(int)
```

**Output** *(using posted actual three columns as .txt files)*

```
# file       GeneName          fileAIB          fileAIC          fileAID
# 0     1700012D01Rik                1                0                0
# 1     A430033K04Rik                0                1                0
# 2              Add3                0                0                1
# 3          Ankrd13c                0                1                0
# 4             Arrb2                0                1                0
# 5           B4galt7                0                0                1
# 6            Cd2bp2                1                0                0
# 7             Cndp2                1                0                0
# 8              Dffb                0                1                0
# 9             Gmeb2                0                0                1
# 10          Gnpnat1                0                0                1
# 11           Inpp5e                0                1                0
# 12            Isg20                1                1                1
# 13           Jmjd1c                1                0                0
# 14          Lamtor2                0                1                0
# 15           Lrrc27                0                0                1
# 16            Nabp1                0                0                1
# 17          Ndufa10                1                1                0
# 18          Plekha4                1                0                0
# 19           Prkaa1                0                0                1
# 20          Rabggta                0                0                1
# 21            Rbm17                0                1                0
# 22             Sc5d                0                0                1
# 23            Smad6                1                0                0
# 24          Thumpd1                1                0                0
# 25            Tubb3                0                1                0
# 26            Wdr90                1                0                0
```

Comment: Parfait you are my hero. Awesome solution. Working super well! I might be starting to love data too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily do this by putting the gene name in the index and creating a column of all ones for with the file name as the column name and then concatenating. This should be done altogether in one for loop. Your current for loop syntax doesn't look right. Try something like the following that assumes you have a one column dataframe with column name 'GeneName' when read from `read_csv`.

```
import os

files= os.listdir("/gene_files")
df_list = []

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header = 0)
    df[file] = 1
    df.set_index('GeneName')
    df_list.append(df)

pd.concat(df_list, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.concat()` with the `axis` attribute. In your case:
`df01 = pd.concat([df01, df], axis=1)`

Before you can use `df.columns = [filename]` in order to give a new dataframe a column name.